# Removing header line and page number

Tags: page-numbering, rules

I'm writing an article, and it gives me a line at the top of the page on which there's a page number.
I want to remove both the line and the page number.

I tried this to remove the line but it didn't work:

```
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
```

This is my whole file:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% file template.tex %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% This is a general template file for the LaTeX package SVJour3
% for Springer journals.          Springer Heidelberg 2010/09/16
%
% Copy it to a new file with a new name and use it as the basis
% for your article. Delete % signs as needed.
%
% This template includes a few options for different layouts and
% content for various journals. Please consult a previous issue of
% your journal as needed.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% First comes an example EPS file -- just ignore it and
% proceed on the \documentclass line
% your LaTeX will extract the file if required
\begin{filecontents*}{example.eps}
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 19 19 221 221
%%CreationDate: Mon Sep 29 1997
%%Creator: programmed by hand (JK)
%%EndComments
gsave
newpath
  20 20 moveto
  20 220 lineto
  220 220 lineto
  220 20 lineto
closepath
2 setlinewidth
gsave
  .4 setgray fill
grestore
stroke
grestore
\end{filecontents*}
%
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%
%\documentclass{svjour3}                     % onecolumn (standard format)
%\documentclass[smallcondensed]{svjour3}     % onecolumn (ditto)
%\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pxfonts}

\graphicspath{ {C:\Users\App\Desktop\MANUSCRIPT\LaTeX} }

%
% \usepackage{mathptmx}      % use Times fonts if available on your TeX system
%
% insert here the call for the packages your document requires
%\usepackage{latexsym}
% etc.
%
% please place your own definitions here and don't use \def but
% \newcommand{}{}

\newcommand*{\tabbox}[2][t]{%
    \vspace{0pt}\parbox[#1][3.7\baselineskip]{1cm}{\strut#2\strut}}

%
% Insert the name of "your journal" with
% \journalname{myjournal}
%
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=7cm]{twoapproaches.pdf}
\caption{Two approaches to mutli-class vehicle classification}
\label{fig:1}      
\end{figure}

\end{document}
% end of file template.tex
```

Comment: The `svjour3` class is used for submissions to Springer journals; they want the rule. If you aren't submitting a paper, avoid using the class.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a documentclass provided by a journal as required for a paper submission. If that is the case then pretty clearly you should not make any layout modifications.

Otherwise, use any documentclass that best suits your needs - or, if allowed, make a *copy* of the .cls document, change its name, and edit in any changes to the layout you may require. But this is somewhat advanced stuff. I would recommend you focus on content and not worry about formatting.

Comment: Yes I am writing using the journal's documentclass, however they require that all figures be provided on separate files - without the lines and page numbers formatting.

Comment: But do these separate figures need to be compiled with the same class ?